# Is there a way of Service Discovery that works on localhost and Kubernetes without changing a line of code?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

I’m currently working with spring boot and kubernetes and came across a problem.
I’ve already implemented service discovery in spring boot with spring-boot-cloud-kubernetes and it’s working fine, but (and this is something I’m not stoked about) I have to redeploy my microservices to minikube every time I want to observe the changes. Is there a way to use local service discovery (localhost) that also works within kubernetes without using Eureka, etc?

Comment: Is this the same: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47178056/1061413 ? If so, maybe the answer there will help.

Answer (score 3):

You could use Consul in combination with [consul-template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template) or [envconsul](https://github.com/hashicorp/envconsul) to do service discovery and config file templating, including automatic restarting of the application if required.

Answer (score 0):

Use k8s services that point to respective endpoints. You can always change the service endpoints and will be reflected any time there are changes to services.